# SQL - SET and IGNORE in one statement

Tags: php, mysql

Having some issues with the SQL syntax here when trying to insert CSV data into my table, while at the same time updating the "TIMESTAMP" column (note: I know this can be done via the table structure auto-update, but that doesnt work for me here...) but also have to ignore the first 3 rows.

So in short

1. Insert CSV data
2. Update TIMESTAMP column
3. IGNORE first Three rows

Code:

```
$sql= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$import_file."' INTO TABLE `$dbtable`
                       FIELDS TERMINATED BY '".$fieldseparator."'
                       LINES TERMINATED BY '".$lineseparator."'
                       SET TIMESTAMP = '".date('Y-m-d H:m:s')."', IGNORE 3 LINES";
```

All that in statement, can this be done? SQL is throwing an error with the `IGNORE 3 LINES` line.

Answer (score 0):

`SET` comes after everything else.

```
$sql= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$import_file."' INTO TABLE `$dbtable`
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '".$fieldseparator."'
   LINES TERMINATED BY '".$lineseparator."'
   IGNORE 3 LINES
   SET TIMESTAMP = '".date('Y-m-d H:m:s')."'";
```